# How to fix this assembly error vb.net project on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm copying my project from other PC but after opening my project I got a warning icon on my references.and when I open the designer it will show error file. how can I find the references dll or to fix this trouble?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to start solving this problem by installing the components you use, like you did on the source machine.  So at least DevExpress and whatever provided MapXLib and StdType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See on the PC from which you are copying from where these assemblies are located. You should copy/register assemblies on your PC. If these assemblies are part of third party library, usually it means that your need to install that third party library.